# getting a value of a known key in php failing

Tags: php, json

I know it's my syntax, but can't find the problem.

I normally use a loop to turn any json keys into variables like this:

Sent `JSON:  [{\"name\":\"dolly\",\"page\":\"A4\"}]`

```
$object = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myData']));

foreach ($object[0] as $key => $value)
{   
    $$key = preg_replace('/--+/',' ',$value);   
}
```

So now, eg, I have $page = "A4". Works fine.

Now, rather than looping through like that, I just want to access the 'page' key (that I know is going to be there every time), and disregard anything else.

I thought this would do it, but it falls over with "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array":

```
$object = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myData']));

$page = $object[0]['page'];
```

This doesn't error out, but it returns nothing:

```
$object = json_decode($_POST['myData']);

$p = $object[0]->page;
```

As does

```
$p = $object->page;
```

What am I screwing up here?

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($object)`?

Comment: Why does your JSON have slashes before the quotes? That's not valid JSON.

Comment: @Barmar It's coming from a POST request so PHP auto-adds them, and there is a `stripslashes` call to remove them.

Comment: PHP shouldn't add them unless you have `magic_quotes_gpc` turned on. That misfeature is deprecated.

Comment: @Barmar My site still has them, and it's in a web hosting service so I can't change it either.

Comment: It should be noted that dumping user-posted data into arbitrary global variables is an unbelievably bad idea.

Comment: The first error message can be fixed by using `json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myData']), true)`.

Comment: Sammitch - isn't it fine as long as you sanitize the global vars before using them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to combine your approaches ;-)

```
$object = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['myData'])); // note the stripslashes() here!
$p = $object[0]->page;
```

As the object encoded is an array, you do need to get the first element and then the object property as you did in your second snippet of code. You just forgot to apply `stripslashes()` so that `json_decode()` failed.

Comment: Thanks you guys - that ended a couple of hours of frustration!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine for me?

```
$a='[{\"name\":\"dolly\",\"page\":\"A4\"}]';
$o=json_decode(stripslashes($a));
var_dump($o[0]->page);
```

string(2) "A4"

Does that help?